# Determine the area of triangle PQR in terms of triangle XYZ

Tags: triangles

[image]

Any Ideas on How to Begin ?

Begin Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

Construct a line OP parallel to QR.

Hint 2:

Consider the relationship between the areas of XYZ and XQR.

Hint 3:

Consider the relationship between the areas of XQR and PQR.

Comment: QY=YZ=ZR , as the base of XQR is thrice triangle XQR it's area should be thrice XYQ I guess? ; At a glance It looks like that area of XQR is half the area of the triangle PQR